# Turn a set of divs into a link

Tags: html, css

I have list elements like this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div>Head</div>
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

what i want to have is a link over the whole outer div like if you wrap it with  (But unfortunately that ist not valid)

I know that it is possible to use "display:block" for an "a" Tag inside a div to get it to the full size of the div, but unfortunately the size of the divs depend on the (dynamic) content and therefore is not set via css. This means that if I set width and height for said "a" Tag to 100%, then it will take the size of the parent of the outer div.

Is there a valid solution to this?

Comment: what u exact want?? not cleared :(

Comment: that it is possible to click anywhere in the outer div to follow the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following might work:

```
<div class="outer">
    <a href="" class="spec_link"></a>
    <div>Head</div>
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.outer{ position:relative;}

.outer .spec_link{
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
}
```

the link will wrap itself around the outer no matter it's size. I do something similar for blocks with transparency

Comment: Yes that is what i was looking for. I almost had it myself, the Problem was the missing position on the outer element. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked. To position absolutely according to a div you always set the parent to position relative :)

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the `div` to `span` and set them to `display:block`

```
<a href="..." class="forced">
    <span class="outer">
        <span>Head</span>
        <span>Content</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

and use a css rule of

```
.forced, .forced .outer, .forced .outer > span{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Best solution, standards compliant. +1

Answer (score 1):

Using a bit of JavaScript you can achieve this effect:

```
<div class="outer" style="cursor:pointer;" 
    onclick="document.location='somepage.html';">
  <div>Head</div>
  <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is something strangely offensive about this...what is going to indicate to users without a mouse that the div is clickable. What is a screen reader or spider going to make of it. What visual cues will indicate to the user that it is a clickable element, unless they move their mouse it? What if javascript is disabled?

Comment: Using JS for such a simple task is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the link with Javascript:

```
<div class="outer" onclick="window.location.replace('yourlink.html');">
    <div>Head</div>
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for a pure css solution. Jquery allows you to bind a click event:

```
jQuery('.outer').click(function() {
  window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="...">
<div>
...
</div>
</a>
```

is valid with HTML5.